Pine Script array syntax to display ROC on multiple instruments (BTC, ETH, etc)
The script below displays the rate of change (ROC) for multiple instruments (in this case, four BYBIT alt coins), as well as calculating the average ROC.  It works, but I need some help with syntax to enable the functionality within an array (last half of the script).  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Feel free to use and share!
//@version=5
indicator(title="Multi Instrument Rate Of Change")
numBars = 100
plot(ta.roc(close,numBars),color = color.red,linewidth = 1)

symbol2 = input.symbol("BYBIT:AVAXUSDT.P", title="AVAX")
symbol2Close = request.security(symbol2, timeframe.period, close[1],
     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(ta.roc(symbol2Close,numBars), color=color.orange, title="AVAX")

symbol3 = input.symbol("BYBIT:BTCUSDT.P", title="BTC")
symbol3Close = request.security(symbol3, timeframe.period, close[1],
     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(ta.roc(symbol3Close,numBars), color=color.blue, title="BTC")

symbol4 = input.symbol("BYBIT:DOGEUSDT.P", title="DOGE")
symbol4Close = request.security(symbol4, timeframe.period, close[1],
     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(ta.roc(symbol4Close,numBars), color=color.green, title="DOGE")

symbol5 = input.symbol("BYBIT:ETHUSDT.P", title="ETH")
symbol5Close = request.security(symbol5, timeframe.period, close[1],
     lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(ta.roc(symbol5Close,numBars), color=color.yellow, title="ETH")

averageROC = math.avg(ta.roc(close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol2Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol3Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol4Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol5Close,numBars))
plot(averageROC,color=color.white, title="Average") 

fastAverage = ta.sma(averageROC, 5)
slowAverage = ta.sma(averageROC, 10)

plot(fastAverage, color=color.aqua,title="Fast MA",linewidth = 3)
plot(slowAverage, color=color.fuchsia,title="Slow MA",linewidth = 3)


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Array (need help to get working)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

ia = array.new_string()
array.push(ia,"1000000MOGUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"10000SATSUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"10000WENUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"1000BEERUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"AVAXUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"BTCUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"DOGEUSDT.P")
array.push(ia,"ETHUSDT.P")


string labelText = ""
for i = 0 to (array.size(ia) == 0 ? na : array.size(ia) - 1)
        
    string name = array.get(ia, i)
    string iname = "BYBIT:" + name

    // *********************************************************
    // The syntax of the lines below is incorrect - please help 
    //nextSymbol = input.symbol(iname, title=name)
    //nextSymbolClose = request.security(nextSymbol, timeframe.period, close[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
    //plot(ta.roc(nextSymbolClose,numBars), color=color.orange, title=name)

    // Also need to calculate and display average ROC value of all data in the array
    // averageROC = math.avg(ta.roc(close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol2Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol3Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol4Close,numBars),ta.roc(symbol5Close,numBars))
    // plot(averageROC,color=color.white, title="Average") 
    // *********************************************************


    // Debug to display all names in array
    //labelText += iname + "\n"

// Debug to display all names in array
//label.new(bar_index, high, text = labelText)


// Future upgrades:
// Ability to filter instruments from BYBIT based on volatility, percent change, correlation to BTC, etc ...
// Convert to a strategy with buy/sell signals and trade management for multiple instruments


